# Replacing a part of string in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace a part of string in a dataframe. For example,

```
df =
index                    group
2019-02-01 09:30:07     8157_S1
2019-02-01 09:30:23    S_1.M_01
2019-02-01 09:30:38    S_1.M_02
2019-02-01 09:32:11    S_1.M_08
2019-02-01 09:32:27    S_1.M_12
2019-02-01 09:32:42    S_1.M_11
2019-02-01 09:32:57    S_1.M_10
2019-02-01 09:33:13    S_1.M_09
2019-02-01 09:33:30     8157_S2
2019-02-01 09:33:47    S_2.M_13
```

I want to remove "8157_" and "S_1." and "S_2.". My present code is

```
df['group'] = df['group'].replace("8157_", "") 
df['group'] = df['group'].replace("S_1.","")
```

There was no change in the output.

But my expected output is

```
df =
index                    group
2019-02-01 09:30:07    S1
2019-02-01 09:30:23    M_01
2019-02-01 09:30:38    M_02
2019-02-01 09:32:11    M_08
2019-02-01 09:32:27    M_12
2019-02-01 09:32:42    M_11
2019-02-01 09:32:57    M_10
2019-02-01 09:33:13    M_09
2019-02-01 09:33:30     S2
2019-02-01 09:33:47    M_13
```

Comment: use df['group'].str.replace

Comment: Or add `regex=True` to your `replace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pandas.Series.str.replace`:

```
df['group'] = df['group'].str.replace("S_[12]\.|8157_","") 
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                 index group
0  2019-02-01 09:30:07    S1
1  2019-02-01 09:30:23  M_01
2  2019-02-01 09:30:38  M_02
3  2019-02-01 09:32:11  M_08
4  2019-02-01 09:32:27  M_12
5  2019-02-01 09:32:42  M_11
6  2019-02-01 09:32:57  M_10
7  2019-02-01 09:33:13  M_09
8  2019-02-01 09:33:30    S2
9  2019-02-01 09:33:47  M_13
```

Comment: Just great! your one line code did exactly what I wanted. In between, `S_[12]\.` means what?

Comment: It means replace `S_{1 or 2}\.`. Note the backslash for `\.`; without it, `.` is interpreted as _any char_ which is not in your case.